# How to conditionally copy a row in google sheets to a tab in a loop but not duplicating

Tags: google-sheets

Ok, complete newb here...I've searched and found various 'copy row to another sheet' scripts but can only get one to work. Here is my bodged version below. What I am trying to do is have a front sheet that displays the rows from sheet 1 where one of three criteria is met i.e column N has a status of 'Edit', 'SB Edit' or 'Amend Edit'. The below does do this but it doesn't loop and each time I run it, it repeats the action and I get duplicates of all the rows on the destination sheet.
Essentially, I want it running such that any time the status of column N for a particular row is changed to one of these three values, it shows up on Sheet 2. So Sheet 2 is a 'live' display of all rows in sheet 1 where column N equals the specified value

Any help much appreciated...

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('N:N');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet 2'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

  //Condition check in N:N; If true copy the same row to data array
for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Edit') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,15).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    
    for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Amend Edit') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,15).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
    
        for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'SB Edit') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,15).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }
//Copy data array to destination sheet

 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);


//Delete matched rows in source sheet
  //for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  //var k = j[i]+1;
  //sheet.deleteRow(k);

//Alter j to account for deleted rows
  //if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  //j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that copy to happen when the column N is modified, it's probably best to set a trigger, like [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). That will give you an object with data about the event that happened, including the cell that was changed and its value.

You can then use such data to get the whole row and copy it to the other sheet, like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const statuses = ['Edit', 'SB Edit', 'Amend Edit'];
  
  // Check if the modification happened on column N (14th column) and if the new value is one of the desired statuses
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 14 && statuses.includes(e.value)) {
    // Get sheets
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    
    // Get the whole row of the modified cell 
    const modifiedRow = sheet1.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    // Append modified row to the end of Sheet2
    sheet2.appendRow(modifiedRow.flat());
  }
}
```

If you want to avoid duplicated rows in Sheet2, then you need to have a way to check whether a particular row was added to Sheet2 before.

For example, if column A has a unique identifier (ID) for rows, you can search for that ID in Sheet2 before appending a new row. If it exists, then you might want to replace it with the new values or just do nothing. If it doesn't exist, then you append the row to the end:

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  // Check if the modification happened on column N (14th column) and if the new value is one of the desired statuses
  if (e.range.getColumn() === 14) {
    // Specify update statuses
    const addStatuses = ['Edit', 'SB Edit', 'Amend Edit'];
    const removeStatuses = ['On Hold', 'Version Returned'];
    
    // Get sheets
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    
    // Get the whole row of the modified cell 
    const modifiedRow = sheet1.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    
    // Assume that ID is in column A (first column)
    const modifiedRowID = modifiedRow[0][0];    
    
    // Get values from Sheet2
    const columnValues = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
    
    // Check if Sheet2 already has row based on the value of column A and retrieve its index
    let rowIndex = -1;
    for (let i = 0; i < columnValues.length; i++) {
      if (columnValues[i][0] == modifiedRowID) {    
        rowIndex = i + 1; // JavaScript arrays indices start from 0, but Sheets row indices start from 1
        break;
      }
    }
    
    // If row should be added/removed to/from Sheet2
    if (addStatuses.includes(e.value)) { 
      if (rowIndex == -1) {
        // Row not found in Sheet2, so add it
        sheet2.appendRow(modifiedRow.flat());
      } else {
        // Optional: Row found in Sheet2, so replace it with current values
        sheet2.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, modifiedRow[0].length).setValues(modifiedRow);   
      }
    } else if (removeStatuses.includes(e.value) && rowIndex > -1) {
      // Remove row from Sheet2
      sheet2.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for taking your time to assist...very much appreciated. In trying to get the first part to run (or the 2nd version) I get this error message....I tried google bits of it to fathom it out but, nope, beyond me

TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 5, file "editon")

Comment: That's because you are probably trying to run the function from the editor, but, since it is a trigger, it's called automatically whenever the sheet is modified. How do you plan to execute this function, manually from the editor or let it execute as an automatic trigger?

Comment: Ahh.....that'll be my noobness coming to the forefront again :) Ideally, automatic trigger would be wonderful
  Again, thanks for entertaining my ineptness when its comes to this. The last coding I did as part of my engineering degree involved turbo pascal :)

Comment: No worries :) If you want it as a trigger, then you just need to include that in your Code.gs and save it. Whenever the sheet is edited, the onEdit() function will be called automatically. Here's the sheet I used to test: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10MX_SeQcKypDQNdiFJ2Gt9OcqCCLQWt4fBUyN9Ejenc/

Comment: Got it, understand how the trigger works now. Yup, that works brilliantly. There is one oversight on my part though which I didn't think through. These are tracking animation projects and the projects will be subject to amendments. This ADDS the live projects but doesn't REMOVE the non-live ones. Is there a simple way such that if the status on Sheet 1 changes to 'On Hold' or "Version Returned' it then removes the row from sheet 2? i.e as that status can change between edit and version returned and then back to edit, the rows get copied and then deleted from sheet 2?

Comment: If you haven't got time/energy then totally get it...more than happy to paypal you a 'drink' for helping out...

Comment: Sure, no problem. I rearranged the code a bit and added a condition to check whether the row should be removed from Sheet2 (please check the sample link from my previous comment). Also, just to keep the question focused, I sent you a connection request on LinkedIn so we continue talking there about extensions/modifications.